# Why doesn't `npm prune` remove folders from node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a `package.json` with all my `devDependencies`.

My understanding was that if I remove a dependency, and run `npm prune`, node will remove the module folder from `node_modules`. This seems to be the easiest way to maintain my `node_modules` folder.

From the [docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/prune.html):

> npm prune
>
> Remove extraneous packages
>
> This command removes "extraneous" packages.
>
> Extraneous packages are packages that are not listed on the parent
>   package's dependencies list.

However, sometimes even after running `npm prune` I still have the module folder in my `node_modules`.

Why does this happen and what is the correct way to remove unused modules?

Comment: Do an `npm list`. Is the folder in question a transitive dependency (dependency of a dependency)?

Answer (score 25):

According to [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-prune)

> If the `--production` flag is specified, this command will remove the
> packages specified in your `devDependencies`.

So, if you want to get rid of the module folder in `node_modules` which is specified in `devDependencies`, you shall execute

> `npm prune --production`

Comment: I want to remove folders which are NOT specified in my devDependencies. This is different from what you are suggesting. I want my node_modules folder to include only what is written in my dependencies, not extra modules that were used before.

Comment: by saying "are NOT specified in my devDependencies" you mean they are specified in regular dependencies or they are not present in package.json at all?

Comment: I mean they are not in package.json at all.

Comment: In such case, simple npm prune shall be enough (works on OSX, npm v1.3.11) - it removes all directories from npm_modules which are not listed in package.json

Comment: Yes this is what I thought. I am running Windows with npm 1.3.14.
But I still have folders in node_modules even though they are not in package.json.

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue

Answer (score 9):

After running:

```
npm ls
```

I see:

```
npm ERR! extraneous: package@0.9.6 /path/to/package
```

Then when I did:

```
npm prune
```

The package was uninstalled.